# Multi color image into single color image in canvas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

To explain my example first is the original image.

Edit: Assuming it is placed on canvas using base64 data.

[image: Input]

and this is the output with color applied is #ED7600

[image]

Now the image is converted into single shade. I have tried different canvas built in compositions. But none of them worked. A color manipulation algorithm can do it. I have some starter code so everyone may know the inputs.

```
let color_code = "#ED7600",
    imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    data = imageData.data; // This is the color data I want to manipulate
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    // Awesome algorithm goes here                       
}
```

I have already tried different solutions from stack overflow. But nothing exactly changed a multi color image into a single shade color. I am creating it for a printing company and in their business, single color print costs less so customer can have an option to see how it will look.

Comment: You don't need to access pixels, Just use the 2D API. Draw the image on a canvas, then set fill color to the color you want, set `globalCompositeOperation`  to `"hue"` and fill a rect over it. Eg  `ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); ctx.fillStyle = ""#ED7600"; ctx.globalCompositeOperation="hue"; ctx.fillRect(0,0,image.width,img.height);` to restore comp to default `ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-over"; `

Comment: i was typing an extremely complicated answer when I saw you post this, you should post this as an answer not a comment.